Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal)
I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline through Azure DevOps to test my Terraform code, my organization is planning on switching to CI/CD for our infrastructure.
I am trying to validate Terraform in my Azure tenant through a Service Connection in a YAML Pipeline:
name: Azure Infrastructure CI/CD

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - name: public_key
    value: $(public_key)
  - name: terraformSecret
    value: $(client_secret)

steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true

  - task: TerraformInstaller@0
    inputs:
      terraformVersion: 'latest'

  - script: az login --service-principal -u "$(client_id)" -p $(client_secret) --tenant "$(tenant_id)"
    displayName: 'Azure CLI Login'

  - script: az account set --subscription "$(subscription_id)"
    displayName: 'Azure Subscription Set'
  
  - script: |
      terraform init
      terraform plan -out=tfplan \
        -var="public_key=${public_key}" \
        -var="client_secret=${terraformSecret}"
    displayName: 'Terraform Init and Plan'
    workingDirectory: .

  - script: |
      terraform apply -auto-approve tfplan
    displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
    workingDirectory: .

Here is my Terraform provider file:
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}

    client_id       = "xxxxx"
    client_secret   = var.client_secret
    tenant_id       = "xxxxx"
    subscription_id = "xxxxx"
}

And an excerpt from my variables Terraform variables file:
variable "client_secret" {
  type        = string
}

And I have all environment variables set correctly on the pipeline in Azure DevOps.
I am getting this error:
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: building AzureRM Client: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal).
│ 
│ To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal'
│ auth method - instructions for which can be found here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret
│ 
│ Alternatively you can authenticate using the Azure CLI by using a User Account.
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on providers.tf line 10, in provider "azurerm":
│   10: provider "azurerm" {
│ 
╵

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.


I have checked the Terraform docs, and they don't show how I can authenticate a terraform connection through a script, and I want to protect the client secrete as much as I can, and not make it available for everyone accessing this code. I have also used a bunch of LLMs and the insight is minimally helpful as with most terraform-related projects.
How do I authenticate my terraform code through a service principal on a YAML pipeline?

As per Configuring the Service Principal in Terraform, you can use environment variables to authenticate to the azurerm provider:
export ARM_CLIENT_ID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="12345678-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
export ARM_TENANT_ID="10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

In an Azure pipeline you can set these environment variables at the task level, for all tasks that run terraform commands such as init, plan and apply - example:
  - script: |
      terraform ...
    displayName: 'Run Terraform command'
    workingDirectory: .
    env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(my_client_id)
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(my_client_secret)
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(my_subscription_id)
      ARM_TENANT_ID: $(my_tenant_id)


Regarding:

I want to protect the client secrete as much as I can, and not make it available for everyone accessing this code

One option would be to use variable groups to store the variables used to authenticate to the azurerm provider. Secret variables in variable groups are protected resources, so you can add combinations of approvals, checks, and pipeline permissions to limit access to secret variables in a variable group.
As an alternative, use an Azure Resource Manager service connection with an Azure CLI v2 task or Azure Pipelines Terraform Tasks, as mentioned in Shamrai's answer.

Solution worked, thank you for the advice!

With your sample shared, I can reproduce the same error.
This is because you used incorrect variable syntax ${var} in terraform plan command, the correct format is $(var).
Please fix it as belowL
  - script: |
      terraform init
      terraform plan -out=tfplan \
        -var="public_key=$(public_key)" \
        -var="client_secret=$(terraformSecret)"
    displayName: 'Terraform Init and Plan'
    workingDirectory: .

The task succeeds then:


You may:

Configure a new service connection with your service principal: Connect to Azure by using an Azure Resource Manager service connection
Then use Azure Pipelines Terraform Tasks through the service connection.

